# List Item Anything

Tags: python, python-2.7

So I am writing a tic tac toe game and I am using this as the format of the list:

```
board = [["0", "1", "2"],
         ["3", "4", "5"],
         ["6", "7", "8"]]
```

So when I am writing the ai for the tic tac toe, I faced a problem as these lines,

```
for i in board:
    if i == ["X","X"," "]:
        return i[2]
    elif i == ["X"," ","X"]:
        return i[1]
    elif i == [" ","X","X"]:
        return i[0]
for i in horzboard:
    if i == ["X","X"," "]:
        return i[2]
    elif i == ["X"," ","X"]:
        return i[1]
    elif i == [" ","X","X"]:
        return i[0]
```

it cant work as python is specific on the item, so is there a way which I can tell python this is what I wanted (eg *s are anything):

```
for i in board:
    if i == ["X","X",*]:
        return i[2]
    elif i == ["X",*,"X"]:
        return i[1]
    elif i == [*,"X","X"]:
        return i[0]
for i in horzboard:
    if i == ["X","X",*]:
        return i[2]
    elif i == ["X",*,"X"]:
        return i[1]
    elif i == [*,"X","X"]:
        return i[0]
```

Thanks!

Comment: *it cant work as python is specific on the item,* << **what??**

Comment: *"*s are anything"* -- **anything**?  Normally tic-tac-toe only allows X's and O's. Can you please clarify your question. See [ask] for some tips to improve it.

Comment: * means everying in programming, doesn't it? @DavidZemens

Comment: python is very specific on the items so I am wondering if there is a way to let python know I can allow anything to be placed in the star @DavidZemens

Comment: So you mean "any non-null" value, or in python, any *truthy* value?

Comment: Consider providing a [MCVE] which illustrates the problem you're facing. It's hard to understand what you're trying to do here.

Comment: @ZedNoMercy you can try writing a logic where the winner is not decided unless we have 3 consecutive X or O, doesn't matter what the placeholder looks like

Comment: @DavidZemens What I mean is that * can be anything, it can be "^" or "1" or "a" or anything you can think of. I never thought my English is this bad

Comment: @Uasthana That program extract is from the ComputerMove function. It is not checking if the player or the computer has won.

Comment: Why don't you have a board of `None` and so when it's not `None` you know something is there.

Comment: I understand what "anything" means, but you're not doing yourself any favors by being snarky in your responses (and in the context of a tic-tac-toe game, "anything" shouldn't be allowed as user-input). I'm trying to understand *what your actual problem* is, specifically, so we might make a recommendation for you.

Comment: You could do something like `if row[0] == 'X' and row[1] == 'X'`... but honestly, you *shouldn't* be allowing for *anything*.

Comment: Are you only trying to return one value per board? Without seeing more of your code, it is hard to understand how this is used, but what you have shown suggests that you want this function to stop and return a value the first time it hits a non-'X' value. Is that what you want? Or are you trying to return all available spaces left on the entire board?

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to find values in a board that are not 'X', which is what your sample code suggests, then I would use a function that you can pass either `board` or `horzboard` to, per your example.

```
# This will return a list of all non-X values in the entire board

def return_marks(board):

    mark_list = [(arr,mark) for arr in board for mark in arr if mark != 'X']

        return mark_list

# If you just want the first non-X value to cause the function to stop and return that non-X value, then try this.

def return_marks(board):    
    for row in board:

        for mark in row:

            if mark != 'X':
                return mark
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, however what I look for is to tell python ["X","X", and this can be anything] in a middle of the if statement. Can you help me with that? Appreciated your answer!

Comment: I understand how you have written your code, and you may think it is doing something other than it is, but what your code is actually accomplishing is: "Look at this list of items, if one of them is not 'X', return that item." Accomplishing that task is what my code above does. If the 'X' values from your sample can be something else, then you can simply modify the `if` statements in my code to be `if mark not in ['X','O']`, for example.

Comment: The problem is that you are trying to analyze lists as a whole - the entire list and its contents as one object and checking its contents and order against a pattern. As part of that, you are trying to evaluate if one item in the list is some wildcard value other than 'X', but by definition a list is made up of real objects/values, not wildcard logic expressions. If you want to check each value in the list for whether it is 'X' or a wildcard/"anything else"/non-X, then you need to iterate that list and apply the logic to each value.